# Div alignment not wanting to work

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<ul class="posts">
  <li>
      <a href="">
        <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-part-3/32/square-stack-small-48.png" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="entry">
        <a href="">Nam ultricies dolor eu velit varius scelerisque.</a>
        <span class="date">January 1st, 2013</span>
      </div>
      <div class="floatlimit"></div>
  </li>      
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.blog-container li,ol,ul {  
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.
.blog-container .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        border: none;
    }

  .posts li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
        margin-bottom: 6px;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
        border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);    
        display:block;
  }

 .posts li:last-child {
        margin: 0;
    }

   .posts img {       
        margin: 0px 0px 0 0;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
    }


    .entry .date {
        display: block;
        color: #808080;
    }
```

but it's not showing the img on the left, and the headline text on the right. It's in a container here's what it looks like:

[image]

any ideas? thanks for your help!

http://jsfiddle.net/9fcN5/

Answer (score 2):

Just a Small Change

```
.posts img {       
    margin: 0px 0px 0 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9fcN5/1/)

Comment: works now, thanks. but now it shows my seperator all messed up.  http://screencloud.net/img/screenshots/89f8450a978bee7805e5ac1ba1b07aed.png  http://jsfiddle.net/9fcN5/3/

Comment: show the code for seperator please.. because jsfiddle looks good to me

Comment: I guess because it's in the container itself?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what your looking for?

```
 .posts img {       
            margin: 0px 0px 0 0;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            float: left;
        }
```